Query en symfony
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Symfony para solicitar citas online, y la Query no está funcionando como esperaba. Cuando solicito las citas disponibles para una fecha, me sigue devolviendo las citas guardadas en base de datos con estado 'Confirmada'.
Mi Consulta es:
    public function findAvailableTimesByDate(\DateTime $fecha, $medicoId, $especialidadId)
{

$startOfDay = clone $fecha;
$startOfDay->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$endOfDay = clone $fecha;
$endOfDay->setTime(23, 59, 59);

    //depuración
    error_log('Fecha: ' . $fecha->format('Y-m-d'));
    error_log('Medico ID: ' . $medicoId);
    error_log('Especialidad ID: ' . $especialidadId);

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.fechaHora')
        ->where('c.fechaHora BETWEEN :startOfDay AND :endOfDay')
        ->andWhere('c.medico = :medicoId')
        ->andWhere('c.especialidad = :especialidadId')
        ->andWhere('c.estado != :estadoConfirmado')
        ->setParameter('startOfDay', $startOfDay)
        ->setParameter('endOfDay', $endOfDay)
        ->setParameter('medicoId', $medicoId)
        ->setParameter('especialidadId', $especialidadId)
        ->setParameter('estadoConfirmado', Cita::ESTADO_CONFIRMADA);

    $takenTimes = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    //depuración
    error_log('Taken times: ' . print_r($takenTimes, true));

    // Obtener el turno del médico
    $medico = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(Medico::class)->find($medicoId);
    $turno = $medico->getTurno(); 

    // Definir las horas de inicio y fin basadas en el turno
    $startTime = ($turno === 'manana') ? 8 : 15; // 8h para la mañana, 15h para la tarde
    $endTime = ($turno === 'manana') ? 14 : 20; // 15h para la mañana, 21h para la tarde (última cita comienza una hora antes del fin de turno)

    // Crear todas las posibles horas de inicio de citas dentro del turno
    $startDateTime = clone $fecha;
    $startDateTime->setTime($startTime, 0);
    $endDateTime = clone $fecha;
    $endDateTime->setTime($endTime, 45); // Última cita empieza a las 14:45 o 20:45

    $interval = new \DateInterval('PT15M'); // Intervalo de 15 minutos entre citas
    $period = new \DatePeriod($startDateTime, $interval, $endDateTime);

    //comienzan los cálculos de horas disponibles
    // Obtener la hora actual para filtrar las horas pasadas
    $now = new \DateTime();
    if ($fecha->format('Y-m-d') === $now->format('Y-m-d')) {
        $now = $now->format('H:i:s');
    } else {
        $now = '00:00:00';
    }

    $availableTimes = [];
    foreach ($period as $dt) {
        if ($dt->format('H:i:s') > $now) {
            $availableTimes[] = $dt->format('H:i:s');
        }
    }

    // Eliminar horas ocupadas
    $takenHours = array_map(function ($entry) {
        return $entry['fechaHora']->format('H:i:s');
    }, $takenTimes);

    //depuración
    error_log('Taken hours: ' . print_r($takenHours, true));
    error_log('Available times before filtering: ' . print_r($availableTimes, true));

    $availableTimes = array_diff($availableTimes, $takenHours);

    //depuración
    error_log('Available times after filtering: ' . print_r($availableTimes, true));

    return $availableTimes;
}



}

Y en la entidad Cita tengo los estados definidos:
#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $estado;

    const ESTADO_CONFIRMADA = 'Confirmada';
    const ESTADO_FINALIZADA = 'Finalizada';
    const ESTADO_CANCELADA = 'Cancelada';

¿Alguien sabe dónde puede estar fallando el filtro de citas?
El caso es que con esta consulta, aunque la intención es excluir las citas ya en estado 'Confirmada', aparecen absolutamente todas las citas.

y cual es el  fallo / error???

Me devuelve todas las citas incluyendo las que se han guardado con estado 'Confirmada', que son las que no deberían devolver " ->andWhere('c.especialidad = :especialidadId')"

ok pero eso no tiene nada que ver ... el problema es el operador no deberias usar  <> en lugar de !=  ..... y Cita::ESTADO_CONFIRMADA deberias validar que se esta pasando al query ...

¿La consulta muestra los resultados correctos si la pruebas directamente en la base de datos? ¿Revisaste el depurador de consultas y los resultados que arroja?

Sí, muestra los resultados correctos en base de datos. Por los logs, lo único que saco en claro es que la consulta no está recogiendo los datos de la base de datos.

¿Qué quieres decir con lo único que saco en claro es que la consulta no está recogiendo los datos de la base de datos? Si no los recoge de la base de datos, ¿de dónde los está recogiendo? En el Symfony Profiler, en la parte inferior, puedes abrir la opción de consultas a la base de datos (es el iconito de base de datos que tiene al lado el tiempo de ejecución de las consultas)  y examinar todo. Hace unos meses me ocurrió que cierto código no arrojaba los datos esperados y el error en mi caso era que estaba conectando a una base de datos que no era.
